# Drag and drop TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net

somebody can help me to realise a drag and drop in a TableLayoutPanel please. For a drag and drop normal it's easy but here it isn't cause there is controls which are PictureBox.
I have to slide an image from the TableLayoutPanle_main to a PictureBox in TableLayoutPanle_plateau

Here's what i have try :

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel_main_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel_main.MouseMove
    Dim rep As DragDropEffects

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        rep = sender.DoDragDrop(sender.Controls, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TableLayoutPanel_plateau_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel_plateau.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TableLayoutPanel_plateau_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel_plateau.DragDrop
    If TypeOf sender.Controls Is PictureBox Then
        Dim pb As PictureBox = CType(sender.Controls, PictureBox)
        pb.Image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting drag drop behaviour? Are you getting errors?

Comment: This is a pretty fundamentally wrong approach.  A TableLayoutPanel is supposed to be filled with controls.  That's its reason for being.  So those controls get the mouse events and the drag+drop notifications.  Not the panel.  You'll have to re-think this, consider the D+D notifications of the PictureBoxes instead.

Comment: Yeah but i can't do : Private Sub TableLayoutPanel_plateau_Controls_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel_plateau.Controls.DragDrop
How do i access the drag drop event of the controls ?